# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in codeigniter

Tags: javascript

I am sending session ip address controller to view and taking this variable in javascript function but i am getting an error.

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
function allowip(ip) {

  var ip = prompt("Please enter your ip address", ip);
  if (ip == null || ip == "") {

   alert('fill it please');

  } else {
   alert('ok');
  }}
```

Comment: in view
onclick="allowip(<?php echo  $ip_address;  ?>);">

Comment: No error in this code.Can you post exact error line code or a working fiddle

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: it is taking 31
but not taking 127.0.0.1

Comment: i don't know your argument list and line 31. provide a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) .And you are mention that in codeigniter. But the problem arrived in js

Comment: can you post full js code, problems seems to be in rest of the code.

Comment: this is all i have

Comment: this is in my view page

Comment: it is working fine when i send id which 31 or whatever it is but when i send ip adress
i m getting error.

Comment: Try sending `127.0.0.1` by adding quotation around it i:e "127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`127.09.01` is not a valid number. Instead surround it with the `quotation mark`.

```js
function allowip(ip) {
    // var ip = prompt("Please enter your ip address", ip);
    if (ip == null || ip == "") {
     alert('fill it please');
    } else {
     alert(ip);
    }
}

allowip("127.09.01");
```